# Creating sequence of integers that skips k elements every n elements

Tags: python, numpy

What's the easiest/most elegant way to create a sequence of integers such that every *n* elements *k* numbers are omitted, in numpy?

The sequence is big and I want to avoid as much as possible for-loops.

E.g.:

```
n = 4
k = 2

desired output = {0,1,2,3,6,7,8,9,12,13,14,15,...}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
seq = numpy.arange((n+k)*10).reshape(-1,n+k)[:,:n].flatten()
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. But it can't be reshaped in the case of an arbitrary sequence of length N that is not divisible by n+k.

Comment: What do you want to do with this sequence?

Comment: I want to slice an array.

Answer (score 1):

Create as many repeats of your base `n` range sequence as you will need, offset each by the right amount, flatten and discard extra items:

```
def skip_range(n, k, length):
    N = (length - 1) // n + 1 # rounded up integer division
    out = np.empty((N, n), dtype=np.intp)
    out[:] = np.arange(0, N*(n+k), n+k)[:, None]
    out += np.arange(n)
    out.shape = (-1,)
    out.resize(length)
    return out

>>> skip_range(4, 2, 7)
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8])
>>> skip_range(4, 2, 8)
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> skip_range(4, 2, 9)
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  6,  7,  8,  9, 12])
```